# Chisquared distribution test in R

Tags: distributions, self-study, normal-distribution, copula, chi-squared-distribution

I'm reading the paper by [Lourme A. et al (2016)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.econmod.2016.12.014) and try to plot the Fig.2 from this paper. The question regarding to programming of confidence areas and my example in `R` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310989/how-to-draw-an-alpha-confidence-areas-on-a-2d-plot).

> 4.1.2. Confidence areas
>
> Let $u = (u_1,…,u_d)^\top$ be a random vector with uniform margins on
>   $(0, 1)$ and let $y = (y_1,…, y_d)^\top \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be defined
>   by: $y_j = G(u_j)$, $j \in \{1,…,d\}$ where $G$ is a continuous
>   increasing map defined between 0 and 1.
>
> Let us assume that the multivariate c.d.f of $u$ is a Gaussian copula
>   with parameter $R_g$. Taking the quantile function of $N_1(0, 1)$ as
>   $G$, then $y$ is distributed as $N_d(0, R_g)$ and the random variable
>   $y^\top R_g^{-1} y$ as $\chi^2_d$. Given $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, the latter
>   variable $y^\top R_g^{-1} y$ is less than $\chi^2_{d,\alpha}$ – the
>   $\alpha$ order quantile of $\chi^2_d$ – with probability $\alpha$.
>   Hence, $$\Gamma_g(\alpha) = \{ v= (v_1 ,…,v_d )^\top \in [0, 1]^d :\\
> (G(v_1),…, G(v_d)) R_g^{-1}(G(v_1),…, G(v_d))^\top \leq\chi^2_{d,\alpha}\}$$ is a $d$-dimensional compact confidence area
>   inside (resp. outside) of which $u$ falls with probability $\alpha$
>   (resp. $1-\alpha$).

$R_g$ is a $d × d$ correlation matrix.

**Question.** I have statistical questions about distribution.

How to statiscally check whether variable $y^\top R_g^{-1} y$ is distributed as $\chi^2_d$?

[It's known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) that mean $M(\chi^2_d)=d$, and variance $D(\chi^2_d)=2d$, where `d` is degreee of freedom.

**Edit.** Is it  possible to use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test here?